# how to get first n characters from field value using string functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trim a value of html field but I can't
here is my code

```
var string=document.getElementById("id").value;
var length = 6;
var trimmedString = string.substring(0, length);
document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML=trimmedString;
```

html code:

> `<textarea id="id"></textarea> <div id="id2"></div>`

but data in div (id2) does not change
help!!

Comment: Can you explain what's going wrong ?

Comment: Some sample input, expected output and actual output would be useful. Do you want to `trim` your string in the conventional sense (remove whitespace from start and end) or simply extract the first `length` characters?

Comment: You aren't trimming a string, but also returning it just as it is, if you want to trim it like it is in `php` see my post

Comment: I have edited my question, have a look at it guys,thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Is your `JavaScript` above the html tags ?

Comment: no at the end of the page

Comment: [Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m93hm/) containing exactly what you have above. It works. What is different about your situation? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function trim( str ) { // removes whitespaces from the beginning and from the end of the specified string, returns trimmed string
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}

var arr = ["  one ", " two", "three "];

arr.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(trim(value));
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LPAbQ/)

Comment: your solution is perfectly fine for whitespace trimming, for fixed length trimming the op's idiom is more efficient and should work as shown; probably the element's `value` attribute is empty.

Comment: @collapsar I don't think that fixed length could be useful in any way, seems to be illogical for me

Comment: @collapsar Also what about if string starting with whitespaces ?! In this case it won't trim a string

Comment: yes, as i said, for whitespace trimming its fine. however, in fixed-format strings you know beforehand about the offsets of the  interesting parts.

Comment: @collapsar Yes, whatever, I provided conventional way of a string trimming :)